# Change search bar height in UITableView (swift 5)

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift5, searchbar

I was follow this [example](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4363809-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started) to implement searching in table view. But I don't use Navigation Controller, so I add Search Bar directly to TableViewHeaderView. The search is working fine, but I need to change the height of  the search bar.
I tried to add constraints to text field, and it changed the bar height, but after searching the Bar stucks over the tableView.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRt7S.png)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I did: setup my constraints for TextField in a search bar. Disable "Cancel" button appearance (otherwise it will overlap the search bar).

```
 func configureSearch() {
    
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = false        
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search station"
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
    
    if let searchField = searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
        
        searchField.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.height.equalTo(55)
            make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(20)
            make.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(-20)
        }
                    
        searchField.textColor = .white
        searchField.backgroundColor = .black
        searchField.font = UIFont(name: "SFUIText-Regular", size: 14)
    }
    tableView.tableHeaderView  = searchController.searchBar
    
}
```

To disable searchController (normally Cancel button do this job ), I add tapGesture:

```
 let searchTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(searchTap)

@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {       
    searchController.isActive = false
}
```